# How do I run python file without path?

Tags: python, module, system

To avoid type in long path name, I am trying to create a folder to put all my .py file in. And I want it to be some sort of "default" folder that every time I run .py file, the system will search this folder to look for that file.

One solution i figured, is to put my .py file in those module folders like "python\lib", and I can call python -m filename.

But I do not want to make a mess in the lib folder.

Is there any other ways to do it? Thanks!

Comment: can't you do this by installing your scripts with `pip` or `pip -e` or the conda equivalents or something and then simply doing `python -m script` (without `.py`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're running Python on Windows (the '\' backslash is my only clue). If so, I think you've got at least one reasonable option.

Create a python_run.bat file similar to this:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM *** MODIFY THE NEXT LINE TO SPECIFY THE LOCATION OF YOUR SCRIPTS ***
SET SCRIPT_DIR=C:\Path\To\Scripts

REM *** MODIFY THE NEXT LINE TO SPECIFY THE LOCATION OF YOUR PYTHON.EXE ***
SET PYTHON_BIN=C:\Python27\python.exe

PUSHD %SCRIPT_DIR%
%PYTHON_BIN% %*
POPD
```

Then make sure the folder where the python_run.bat is located is in your [`PATH` environment variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm). So if the script lives in `C:\Path\To\Scripts\python_run.bat`, you'd make sure your `PATH` environment variable had `C:\Path\To\Scripts` in it.

Then you simply have to type the following to execute any script located in your SCRIPT_DIR.

```
python_run my_cool_script.py --foo=bar
```

And it will result in running the following command as if you were already inside your scripts folder:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe my_cool_script.py --foo=bar
```

Comment: can't you do this by installing your scripts with `pip` or `pip -e` or the conda equivalents or something and then simply doing `python -m script` (without `.py`)?

Comment: @CharlieParker The OP wanted to know how they could run their scripts without specifying a path. To run a script with the `-m` flag you'd have to follow the convention [described in python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) of executing your script with the `-m` flag. That said, and as you suggest, an alternative could be to follow the convention and use the `-m` flag.

Answer (score 1):

for example: first type

sys.path.append("/home/xxx/your_python_folder/")

then you can import your own .py file

Comment: can't you do this by installing your scripts with `pip` or `pip -e` or the conda equivalents or something and then simply doing `python -m script` (without `.py`)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that without path. The only thing that you can is putting all of modules that you want to use in the same directory, you don't have to put them `python\lib` , you can put them in a folder on your desktop for example.Then run your scripts in that folder but, always be sure starting scripts with `#!/usr/bin/env python`.